# file permission error when checking filename in ksh

Tags: ksh

I'm trying to create a checksum file.
The file will have a list of files from the working directory, create cksums for each file, and drop the list of files with their cksums as MD5_<>.txt along with the files.

The code I have is as follows:

```
EXT=`date +%Y%m%d`
p_FP=${gp_LOAD_DIR}Client/

cd ${p_FP}
###################################################
# Create MD5_<<Process Date>>.txt File
###################################################
echo "MD5 CHECKSUM Roster for " ${EXT} > MD5_${EXT}.txt
echo "MD5        File Size     FileName" >> MD5_${EXT}.txt
for file in $p_FP*; do
     if $file != MD5_${EXT}.txt]; then
        echo cksum file >> MD5_${EXT}.txt
     fi
done
```

for some reason the if line is giving me `"Permission Denied"` errors in spite of the fact it is the same user who created the file.  I suspect that `$file` is an object, not a text name of a file.  how do I rectify this?

Comment: Actually, your if test should be between [[...]] as to not try to execute the $file. On the other hand, you should not "echo" to the file since you will end up with the literal "cksum file" in your file (by the way it should be $file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for fun, that's what I would do including some formatting to ease the reading of the result file.

```
    #!/bin/ksh

    # This is just for formatting

    typeset -L15 Col1
    typeset -L15 Col2
    typeset -L50 Col3

    # Shouldn't use backtick, it's more or less deprecated by now
    EXT=$(date +"%Y%m%d")
    p_FP=${gp_LOAD_DIR}Client/

    cd ${p_FP}
    ###################################################
    # Create MD5_<<Process Date>>.txt File
    ###################################################

    # Just for speed. Since you are already using cksum for each line, it could be faster to avoid reopening the result file each time also

    exec 3>MD5_${EXT}.txt

    # Using ksh, you should use "print" instead of echo since it's builtin instead of external (faster)
    print -u 3 "MD5 CHECKSUM Roster for " ${EXT}

    Col1="MD5"
    Col2="File Size"
    Col3="FileName"

    print -u 3 "$Col1$Col2$Col3"

    for file in $p_FP*; do
        # cksum won't work on directories nor on names pipe
         if [[ -f $file && ! -p $file && $file != MD5_${EXT}.txt ]]; then
            # Again, that's just for formatting
            line=( $(cksum $file) )
            Col1=${line[0]}
            Col2=${line[1]}
            Col3=${line[2]}
            print -u 3 "$Col1$Col2$Col3"
         fi
    done

    # Closing the file

    exec 3>&-
```

Answer (score -1):

You are calling the program `$file`with the arguments `!=`and `MD5_${EXT}.txt]`

So the most probable reason is that `$file` is not executable (the x bit was not set).

If you like to **test** something, you should prepend `$file` with `test` and remove that probably stray `]` before the semicolon.

Comment: the intent of that if statement is to just make sure I don't try to chksum the MD5 file itself.  how do I ensure that?

Comment: OK, I edited my test to make the word "test" bold